# 2006 Ford Explorer turns over then starts making clicking noise and completely stops everything

Tags: ford, starting

I have a 2006 Ford Explorer Eddie Bauer. I just got the alternator changed, cost 450. I have no money to get anything else done. Yesterday we had a big storm come through and it’s now 30 degrees out. My car tries to turn over then starts clicking again. I have a new battery and alternator. I also just got the car a month or two ago. What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Did you charge the new battery before installing it?  It might be that it simply doesn't have enough energy to start the engine at this time.

Comment: I sent it back to the mechanic I bought it from

Comment: Welcome to this group.  How many miles on this vehicle?

Comment: Sure sounds like a weak/dead battery. Did the vehicle sit for a long period of time between starts?  30 degrees is not generally a big problem for healthy and even less-healthy car batteries.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue, it sounded like it was coming from the throttle body or maybe something under the dash board (maybe both) mine ended up being the positive battery terminal, check the ground as well.

I'm still curious what would cause that noise though.